# Can I stop AngularJS from completely rebuilding a repeated section of the DOM?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Given the following simple module and controller:

```
var t = angular.module("test", []);
t.controller("TestCtrl", function ($scope, $timeout) {

    $scope.arr = [
        "elem1",
        "elem2",
        "elem3"
    ];

    $scope.getDate = function () {
        return +new Date();
    };

    $timeout(function () {
        $scope.arr[2] = "< I should have a different timestamp to the two above me now";
    }, 2000);
});
```

And the following simple template:

```
<ul ng-app="test" ng-controller="TestCtrl">
    <li ng-repeat="x in arr">{{getDate()}} {{arr[$index]}}</li>
</ul>
```

Is there a way I can make the `ng-repeat` directive only update the necessary elements in the DOM, rather than rebuilding the entire set of `li` elements, when a single value in the `arr` property of the model changes?

I would like to be able to render that list so the timestamp against the first 2 elements does not change when the 3rd element is modified after the timeout.

Here's [a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jamesallardice/vx2c3/1/) containing the above example.

**Edit**: please note that the timestamp in this example is only there to demonstrate the issue. My real code is far more complex and is suffering from performance problems due to the number of DOM nodes Angular is recreating every time. Adding the timestamp to the model is not a solution in this case.

Comment: maybe you can keep the timestamps in your `arr`?

Comment: @akonsu - The timestamps are only there to demonstrate the issue. My real code is far more complex and is suffering from performance problems due to the number of DOM nodes Angular is recreating every time.

Comment: I understand now. The only way I see, given that angularjs does not have this optimization, is to split your data into pieces. Same idea as data sharding on the server.

Comment: Is the problem that Angular is re-creating complex DOM nodes (which impacts performance) or that recalculating data for each one of those nodes is impacting performance?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't do this with ngRepeat. It's hard to make other recommendations without knowing more about your particular problem.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it would be to make timestamp a model property.

Here is what i did

http://jsfiddle.net/vx2c3/2/

```
<ul ng-app="test" ng-controller="TestCtrl">
    <li ng-repeat="x in arr" ng-init="t=getDate()">{{getDate()}} and {{t}} {{arr[$index]}}</li>
</ul>
```

That is basically create a model property `t`

Comment: Thanks, but that's not going to help in this case. See the edit and comment on the question.

Answer (score 0):

If you include an expression in a watcher (a `{{curly-brace}}` expression is nothing but a watcher) that returns a different value (curly brace watchers user strict equality (`===`) to detect changes) every time it's called, you will *always* see them updated.

If you want to fix that you have to recompute these expressions outside of watcher expressions  as a response to some more meaningful event.

Using your `getDate()` as an example, you would *have* to include them in your model somehow.
You could for example have a separate array that stores the date for every index of the original array and update both arrays simultaneously.